# Javascript Tabulator Create multi line cells with custom formatter

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I want to create multi line cells with Tabulator using a custom formatter. I get back the values of the cell as an array of strings and want to show each string in one line. Also the lines should toggle in bold and normals style.

This is my approach but its ignoring the "`<br>`" tags and displays all in one line.

```
formatter: function(cell)
                {
                    const results = cell.getValue();
                    if(!results.length)
                        return "";
                    let html = "";                     
                    for(let index = 0; index < results.length; index += 2)
                    {
                        html += "<b>"+results[index]+"</b><br>"+results[index + 1]+"<br>";
                    }
                    return html;
                },
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why your particular approach doesn't work but I have done something similar using a number of `document.createElement` calls. Something like the following in my formatter function:

```
    const v = cell.getValue()
    const el = document.createElement('span');
    const l1 = document.createTextNode(`Line 1: ${v[0]}`);
    const l2 = document.createTextNode(`Line 2: ${v[1]}`);
    el.appendChild(l1);
    el.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    el.appendChild(l2);
    return el;
```

This can be seen in this [Tabulator CodePen](https://codepen.io/shunty/pen/oNyxQLv) in the `bottomAggregateFormatter` function round about line 327 or so.